# Calculating the size of a view

Tags: android

The best way to ask this question is to provide an example, so here it is:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/some_text"
        />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/stretch_me"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/i_can_toggle"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toggle_me"
            android:visibility="gone"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/finished"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This seems fairly simple, but hold on ...

1) I would like the stretch_me layout to take all the remaining space on the screen (and I need its size so I can dynamically populate it from code)

2) I can't change main to RelativeLayout because I would like to toggle toggle_me between gone and visible using the i_can_toggle but need to keep strech_me size the same as before

3) Before changing toggle_me to visible there must be no scroll and finished button must be positioned at the bottom of the screen

Now I have tried many things and the most promising approach was this one with some coding (I was thinking about setting the stretch_me size from code), but I was not able to get the size of the view from my onCreate() method (screen_height - view_height = remaining space).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Once you have views inside a ScrollView there really isn't a useful concept of, "the rest of the size of the screen" anymore. stretch_me is going to stretch enough to fit all of its children on its own and the ScrollView is going to allow scrolling as needed to display all of the content. Are you sure you want this entire layout to be scrollable as a single unit or are you trying to pin some views to the bottom of the screen while the rest of the content scrolls in the area above it?

Answer (score 0):

Set stretch_me to have these attributes to make it take up the space

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: It'll have the view measured twice and fill the space left by other views

Answer (score 0):

> I would like the stretch_me layout to
>   take all the remaining space on the
>   screen

Set the height and weight parameters to the following

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

> I need its size

You can use onmeasure() to measure the view size. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int, int)

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int widthSpec = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    //Similarly for height
}
```

Comment: I don't think I can use this since I have it in a ScrollView